# Why is hook_menu_local_tasks_alter called twice?

Tags: routes, hooks

For some reason, Drupal is calling `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter` twice. This results in either a) doubled tabs or b) really annoying code trying to determine if my custom tabs have already been added.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on here? Why would it be called twice? I'm using PathAuto, is this maybe a redirect issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I solved my problem but not my question. For the time being I think this is the best solution, so I'll post it here for others. Please correct me if I'm wrong because I'm not a Drupal guru or anything.

Still don't know why `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter` is being called twice -- I swear I remember reading it was a two-step process; first for tabs, then for actions, but I don't remember.

Anyway, my solution is pretty simple. It appears that if I change the `data` array in `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter` and include my own key `mymodule_processed` as `TRUE`, it successfully sees that on the second time around and ignores the additional tabs.

Edit, For C&P junkies:

```
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
$map = $router_item['map']; //Map corresponds to the router
if (count($map) >= 2) { //Node views have 2 parameters: [0]=>node,[1]=>node object
    if ($map[0] == 'node') {
        if ( //Ensure we haven't already added the tabs & we have an object of correct type
            !empty($map[1]) &&
            is_object($map[1]) &&
            $map[1]->type == 'post' &&
            !empty($data['mymodule_processed']) && !$data['mymodule_processed']
        ) {
            $data['mymodule_processed'] = TRUE;
            //Add your tabs here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the command line, you can use the following command to return file names and line numbers where this hook is being called.

For example, change directories into your /sites/all/modules directory or other module directory and run,

(assuming your are using mac or linux)

```
$grep "menu_local_tasks" * -rn
```

or as Clive has it below.

```
$grep "drupal_alter(\'menu_local_tasks\'" * -rn
```

*Note, the backslashes escape the single quotes.

Jason.

Comment: That won't work, alter hooks are invoked in a very specific way. You might get away with `drupal_alter('menu_local_tasks'` as the search string

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm not familiar enough with this hook. I'll have to try this out.

Comment: I have searched my project and the only reference to `drupal_alter('menu_local_tasks'` is in `menu.inc`, which is something I would expect. Somewhere I remember reading that perhaps it's called twice on purpose? Once for the Tabs and once for the actions? Could I store info in the data array to indicate that I've already modified it? Or is it going to try to render the array directly?

Comment: You can always just give it a try and see! Are you sure you're not printing a $tabs (primary and/or secondary) variable twice in page template? Can you copy and paste the rendered markup, so we can take a look at it? Oh, are you perhaps duplicating the existing tabs when you add your custom tabs? How are you adding your custom tabs?

Comment: @Jason Hi Jason, sorry I missed this reply. I haven't given it a go yet, but I will very soon. I'm def. not printing my tabs variable twice in any templates, though, as this would result in two identical sets of tabs (separate ULs) instead of new tabs being added to the existing UL.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might suggest a way that I have dealt with this in the past:

```
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {

    // Declare job assignment link path
    $new_tab_path = 'tab-path';

    // Check to see if the the anticipated key for the new tab has already been created. If not, add the tab. If so, skip the tab addition
    if (!isset($data['tabs'][1]['output'][4])) {
        $data['tabs'][1]['output'][] = array(
            '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
            '#link' => array(
                'title' => t('New Tab'),
                'href' => $new_tab_path,
                'localized_options' => array(
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'title' => t('New Tab'),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
      }
    }
```

It basically just tests to see whether or not the index that the new tab will take, in this case key number 4, is set or not.

I'm not too familiar with Drupal yet and I don't know that this is the best way, but it seemed to work to solve the problem of the duplication of tabs.

Comment: This is unreliable, as the number of tabs often times changes when users of different privilege are on the site. For instance, a node view will have an edit tab and maybe a devel tab for an admin, but not for a regular user. Similarly, the webform module also adds tabs for admins but not for regular users.

Comment: Ah yes, I realize this now. I never noticed because the projects I work on only have one role set.